# can i omit the intervening level when using XmlSerializer for a list?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlserializer

my question is best described by a simple example. consider 2 classes like this:

```
class Order {
  [XmlAttribute] int orderId;
  [XmlAttribute] int customerId;
  List<OrderItem> items;
}

class OrderItem {
  [XmlAttribute] int partCode;
  [XmlAttribute] int quantity;
}
```

using XmlSerializer, this will serialize to something like this:

```
<order orderId="...", customerId="..." >
  <Items>
    <orderItem partCode="..." quantity="..." />
  </Items>
</order>
```

what I want to do is remove the <Items> level so that the <orderItem> elements go straight underneath the corresponding <order>

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `XmlElement` attribute:

```
class Order {
  [XmlAttribute] int orderId;
  [XmlAttribute] int customerId;
  [XmlElement]
  List<OrderItem> items;
}
```

With this attribute you can also specify a custom element name for the `OrderItem` objects, or even a different element name for each sub-type of `OrderItem`